# Dynamic SQL - combining 2 tables

Tags: sql

In my Activities table I have columns - Activity, ActivityBaseTable, FieldName

```
**Activity**    **ActivityBaseTable**    **FieldName**
Task            TaskBase                 CreatedOn
Task            TaskBase                 ModifiedOn
```

What I need a sql statement like -

```
select Activity, ActivityBaseTable, FieldName, MIN([Date field], MAX([Date field])
from Activities
```

where the min and max date fields would be -

```
select min(CreatedOn), Max(CreatedOn)
from TaskBase
```

or

```
select min(ModifiedOn), Max(ModifiedOn)
from TaskBase
```

Can this be written as one statement?

Comment: Are the values in `ActivityBaseTable` column **always** `TaskBase`?

Comment: That's the point. I need to select from one the table the values that will determine the last 2 values of my select. And I have dozens of rows with different base ActivityBaseTables and different FieldNames

Comment: @Sebas.. reread the question genius.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't like this as an **answer**, but if you can revise your data model to not use a table name in a column, that would be **much** preferrable.  Please see [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for a great summary of the topic.  I'm cringing when I read that you have `dozens of rows with different base ActivityBaseTables`.  I'm at a loss for a design where this is a good idea.

Depending on your RDBMS, there are lots of examples on this site and others of how to write a stored procedure (which is likely what you'll need) to do this.

**I'm just going to plead with you to change the data model & avoid the situation entirely.**